# i am getting error while using window functions in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, python-3.7, spark2

i am trying to run the below code

```py
employees = (spark.read.format('csv')
             .option('sep', '\t')
             .schema('''EMP_ID INT,F_NAME STRING,L_NAME STRING,
                        EMAIL STRING,PHONE_NR STRING,HIRE_DATE STRING,
                        JOB_ID STRING,SALARY FLOAT,
                        COMMISSION_PCT STRING,
                        MANAGER_ID STRING,DEP_ID STRING''')
             .load('C:/data/hr_db/employees')
)

spec = Window.partitionBy('DEP_ID')

emp = (employees
         .select('JOB_ID', 'DEP_ID', 'SALARY')
         .withColumn('Total Salary', sum('SALARY').over(spec))
         .orderBy('DEP_ID')
)

emp.show()
```

and getting the below error

```py
File "C:\spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o60.showString.java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 56
```

could you please anyone help me on this error?

Comment: Are you sure `'C:/data/hr_db/employees` is the correct filepath?  Does this folder contain ONLY `csv` files, which all have the same schema?  Does it work if you point to a single `csv` file within that folder?

Comment: What is your java version?

Comment: Hi RobinL i am able to read data from this C:/data/hr_db/employees and was able to creating data frame from  it and i was able to display the data by using show() function after data frame created. but i am getting the above error only when i use window functions inside withcolumn()

Comment: C:\Users\earun>java --version
java 12.0.1 2019-04-16
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 12.0.1+12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 12.0.1+12, mixed mode, sharing)  --> This is my java version

Comment: No issue found -after trying as well- in anotebook